# wordpress Hash method + login with wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress, hash

I use some external php I wrote and I want it to be used by `wp_users`.

So, I check user and password - if it matches I `echo` 'logged in'.

In Wordpress documentation it says the Wordpress hash method is MD5!

But when I md5 this (`123321`), I get this:

```
c8837b23ff8aaa8a2dde915473ce0991
```

But the password in my database is saved like this :

```
$P$BKaMz3dTLI9GIspy4Qmk2jPPQ4zv9f1
```

Is there any way to get a hash method in an external php to check if the user is logged in or not? 
This is my code:

```
$userName = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : null;
$userPass = isset($_POST["pass"]) ? $_POST["pass"] : null;
$userPass = md5($userPass);
if ($userName && $userPass ){
    //print_r('SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = "'.$userName.'"');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = '$userName' limit 1";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

      // CHECK PASS
     if($row['password'] == $userPass){
         echo "yeah you logged in";
     }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress no longer uses MD5. [See this](http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/wordpress_password_hasher.php). You can use [is_user_logged_in ()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) to check to see if the user is logged in, or go through the trouble to re-implement the [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/). It is probably best to use the first option and pass the result to your external framework from your Wordpress app.

Comment: dear  i want use code for my mobile application , so i dont think so work with is_user_logged_in () . if you have idea please explain more . thank you

Comment: How is your mobile app *currently* handling authentication? Your best bet is to create an endpoint on your wordpress site that returns the information you need, which is guarded by running `is_user_logged_in`. It sounds like you're trying to insecurely check the password - which defeats the purpose.

Comment: yeah because i dont know how can i create plugin or API in wordpress.
do you have any sample ? thanks